# If statement inside div tag with Razor MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to have an if statement inside a class property of a div tag using the Razor View Engine. How can i get this working and is there perhaps a better way to do this?

```
<div class="eventDay @if(e.Value.Count < 1){Html.Raw("noEvents");}">
```

If there are no events the CSS class *noEvents* should be added. Expected result:

```
<div class="eventDay noEvents">
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
<div class='eventDay @(e.Value.Count<1?"noEvents":"")'>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm and takes up less space. Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

the **Razor Way** is using `<text>`, you also learn more about the Razor syntax [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx) and [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/153/Inline-Razor-Syntax-Overview):

```
<div class="eventDay @if(e.Value.Count < 1) { <text>noEvents</text> }">
```

Comment: I've used <text> tags before when faced with a similar issue, but didn't think of using it now. Thanks for pointing out the error and for the links. Always nice to read up on the syntax and fully understand where and when to use <text> tags.

Comment: This is a more complete answer rather than just printing strings. Very helpful for someone quickly jumping into a large project with no Razor background.

Comment: @DanielChapman you should at least [read this post](http://vibrantcode.com/blog/2012/4/10/whats-new-in-razor-v2.html/) and a second linked inside, so you know a little bit better of the new features of **Razor2** (available as [nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Razor/))... you might like it :)

Comment: @balexandre Thanks! Any information is good information at this point!

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
@{
var css = "eventDay";
if(e.Value.Count < 1){
 css += " noEvents";
}
}
    <div class="@css">
```

Comment: really? this is how you do it?

Comment: no :)
I would use jquery to change appearance based on contents. Here would best be to use String.Format, to remove space from accepted answer:
<div class='@String.Format("{0}{1}", "eventDay" (e.Value.Count<1?" noEvents":""))'>

Comment: jQuery? one more overload for a simple text that the server can do. jQuery is nice for content that changes often, not when we just want to load the page with.

Comment: Well, I said that I would use it, and not that he should use it, as he is making static page. 
If I would be making method that returns _list_ of something, it would be JsonResult, not View, so it does not matter what is in the browser, and looks of result can be changed by editing template by designer who does not have to know razor.

Comment: I would really use this approach as it less of all messes template, specially when there is quite a few `if` - +1.